# R Shiny - iterate over ShinyUI output elements

Tags: r, shiny

I wonder if it is possible to **iterate over ShinyUI output elements**.

In my Shiny application I have a few `uiOutput` elements which are rendered in a very similar way. I would like to refer to them (render them) in a loop, for example with the use of their `id`. I wish to do something like:

```
for(element.id in uiOutput.ids){ 
  output[element.id] <- renderUI({...})
}
```

Of course, such code results in the following error:

```
Error in `[<-.shinyoutput`(`*tmp*`, "some_id", value = function (): 
Single-bracket indexing of shinyoutput object is not allowed.
```

because the correct way (I mean: the only way I know) to refer to an ShinyUI output element is:

```
output$some_id <- renderUI({...})
```

Thank you for any suggestions!!

Comment: Use `output[[element.id]]`. See this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/cZn4vU7U8CU) for more information. If you are using a `for` loop, you might have to wrap the code in `local` to prevent scoping bugs.

Comment: Thank you **Ramnath** a lot for this answer and for the reference link!