# Conditional Sidebar in a shiny app depending on tab selected

Tags: r, csv, tabs, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app where the sidebar is dynamic based on the tab that is selected. The sidebar is populated by a csv file. Right now it is just reading a CSV file named machines.csv. I would want that to be able to read for example austin.csv, dallas.cav based on the tab name. There will be 7 tabs total. Also I am having trouble with the plot area. I want the plot to render to the correct tab (which is always the selected tab).

The code I have is here. The app is at http://45.55.208.171:3838/

Only the first two machines have data right now. And the Dallas tab I can not get to work because it seems I can't use the same render plot ID. Not sure how to make that dynamic based on the tab as well.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(grid)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(lubridate)
library(ggrepel)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(RCurl)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
Machine <-read.csv("machines.csv")
Sys.setenv(TZ="US/Central")
SDate <- Sys.Date()
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Printer Utilization"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                 radioButtons("typeInput", "Machine", t(Machine[1]) , width = 4),
                 dateInput("RepDate", "Date of Report",format = "mm-dd-yyyy",value = "08-03-2016"),
                 downloadButton("downloadplot", "Download")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "plants",
        tabPanel("Austin",value = "Austin", plotOutput("plants",width = "120%",height = "600px")),
        tabPanel("Dallas",value = "Dallas", plotOutput("Dallas",width = "120%",height = "600px")),

        tabPanel("Table", div(DT::dataTableOutput("log"), style = "font-size:50%")))
    )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plants <-renderPlot({
    Sys.setenv(TZ="US/Central")
    SDate <- Sys.Date()
    SDate <-as.POSIXct(SDate,format="%Y%m%d")+18000
    RepDate.1 <- reactive({ as.POSIXct(input$RepDate,format="%Y%m%d", tz="US/Central")}+18000)
    typeInput.1 <- reactive({input$typeInput})
    RDate <- RepDate.1()
    Machine.1<-reactive({subset(Machine,MNames.i==typeInput.1())})
    Serial = Machine.1()$Serial.i
    IP = Machine.1()$IP.i
    Type = Machine.1()$Type.i
    if (Type=="b"){
      if (SDate==RepDate.1())
      {
        extension <- ".ACL"
        logdata <- (read.csv(paste(Serial, as.character(RDate,format="%Y%m%d"), extension, sep = "") , sep = ';'))
        RDate <- RDate-86400
        extension <- ".CSV"
        logdata <- (rbind(read.csv(paste(Serial, as.character(RDate,format="%Y%m%d"), extension, sep = "") , sep = ';'),logdata))
      }
      if (SDate!=RepDate.1())
      {
        extension <- ".CSV"
        try(logdata <- (read.csv(paste(Serial, as.character(RDate,format="%Y%m%d"), extension, sep = "") , sep = ';')))
        RDate <-RDate-86400
        logdata <- (rbind(read.csv(paste(Serial, as.character(RDate,format="%Y%m%d"), extension, sep = "") , sep = ';'),logdata))
        RDate <-RDate+172800
        if (RDate==SDate)
        {extension <- ".ACL"}
        try(logdata <- (rbind(read.csv(paste(Serial, as.character(RDate,format="%Y%m%d"), extension, sep = "") , sep = ';'),logdata)))
      }

      logdata <- subset(logdata, (startdate == as.character(input$RepDate,format="%Y-%m-%d")) | (readydate == as.character(input$RepDate,format="%Y-%m-%d")))
      logdata$jobname <- sub(":.*", "", logdata$jobname)
      logdata$starttime.ct   <- as.POSIXct(paste(logdata$startdate, logdata$starttime, sep = " ", format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", tz="US/Central"))
      logdata$starttime.ct <- force_tz(logdata$starttime.ct,tzone="US/Central")
      logdata$readytime.ct     <- as.POSIXct(paste(logdata$readydate, logdata$readytime, sep = " ", format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", tz="US/Central"))
      logdata$readytime.ct <- force_tz(logdata$readytime.ct,tzone="US/Central")
      logdata$idletime.ct     <- as.POSIXct(logdata$idletime, format = "%H:%M:%S")
      logdata$idletime.hour   <-as.POSIXlt(logdata$idletime.ct)$hour + as.POSIXlt(logdata$idletime.ct)$min/60 + as.POSIXlt(logdata$idletime.ct)$sec/3600
      logdata$activetime.ct     <- as.POSIXct(logdata$activetime, format = "%H:%M:%S")
      logdata$activetime.hour   <-as.POSIXlt(logdata$activetime.ct)$hour + as.POSIXlt(logdata$activetime.ct)$min/60 + as.POSIXlt(logdata$activetime.ct)$sec/3600

      Sreadytime <- (strptime(logdata$readytime.ct,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
      Sstarttime <- (strptime(logdata$starttime.ct,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
      Rtime <- (Sreadytime-Sstarttime)/3600
      Idletime <- (strptime(logdata$idletime.ct,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
      Utilization <- sum(logdata$activetime.hour/24)
      Utilization <- paste(round(Utilization*100,digits=1),"%",sep="")
      output <- format(sum(logdata$nofprinteda4bw)+sum(logdata$nofprinteda3bw*2), big.mark=",")
      ymax.r = (logdata$idletime.hour/(logdata$idletime.hour+logdata$activetime.hour))
      logdata$jobname <- strtrim(logdata$jobname, 18)
    }
    if (Type=="c"){
      url <- paste("http://",IP,"/xjutil/log.csv", sep="")
      dat <- readLines(url) 
      dat <- dat[-1]
      dat <- dat[-1]
      varnames <- unlist(strsplit(dat[1], ",")) 
      nvar <- length(varnames)
      varnames<-make.names(varnames, unique=TRUE)
      k <- 1 
      dat1 <- matrix(NA, ncol = nvar, dimnames = list(NULL, varnames))

      while(k <= length(dat)){
        k <- k + 1
        #if(dat[k] == "") {k <- k + 1
        #print(paste("data line", k, "is an empty string"))
        if(k > length(dat)) {break}
        #}
        temp <- dat[k]
        # checks if there are enough commas or if the line was broken
        while(length(gregexpr(",", temp)[[1]]) < nvar-1){
          k <- k + 1
          temp <- paste0(temp, dat[k])
        }
        temp <- unlist(strsplit(temp, ","))
        message(k)
        dat1 <- rbind(dat1, temp)
      }

      dat1 = dat1[-1,]     
      logdata<-as.data.frame(dat1)

      logdata$starttime.ct <-strptime(logdata$timestamp.printing,format="%Y %m %d %H %M %S", tz="US/Central")
      logdata$readytime.ct <-strptime(logdata$timestamp.done.printing,format="%Y %m %d %H %M %S", tz="US/Central")

      logdata$date.timestamp.printing <- as.character(substr(logdata$timestamp.printing, 1, 10))
      logdata$date.timestamp.done.printing <- as.character(substr(logdata$timestamp.done.printing, 1, 10))

      logdata <- subset(logdata, (date.timestamp.printing == as.character(RepDate.1(), format = "%Y %m %d")) | (date.timestamp.done.printing == as.character(RepDate.1(), format = "%Y %m %d")))
      logdata$title <- sub(":.*", "", logdata$title)

      logdata$activetime <- logdata$readytime.ct - logdata$starttime.ct
      Utilization <- sum(logdata$activetime/86400)
      Utilization <- paste(round(Utilization*100,digits=1),"%",sep="")

      output<-format(sum(as.numeric(logdata$total.pages.printed)),big.mark = ",")
      output<-""
      ymax.r = 0
      logdata$jobname <- logdata$title
      logdata$jobname <- strtrim(logdata$jobname, 18)
    }
    if (Type=="a"){
      url <- paste("http://",IP,"/logs/","?C=M;O=D", sep="")
      html <- paste(readLines(url), collapse="\n")
      matched <- str_match_all(html, "<a href=\"(1100.*?)\"")
      links <- matched[[1]][, 2]
      print(links)
      for (i in links[1:15])
      {
        url <- paste("http://",IP,"/logs/", sep="")
        url.a <- paste(url,as.character(i) ,sep = "")
        print(url.a)
        if (exists("logdata")){
          logdata <- rbind(read.csv(url.a, header=TRUE, fill = TRUE, sep = ","), logdata)
        }
        else{
          logdata <- read.csv(url.a, header=TRUE, fill = TRUE, sep = ",")
          print(url.a)
        }
      }
      logdata$size <- logdata$SqFt
      logdata <- logdata %>% distinct(Start.time, .keep_all = TRUE)
      logdata$Start.time <- strptime(logdata$Start.time, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
      logdata$Total.time <- as.POSIXlt(logdata$Total.time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
      logdata$Total.time <- as.POSIXlt(logdata$Total.time)$hour + as.POSIXlt(logdata$Total.time)$min/60 + as.POSIXlt(logdata$Total.time)$sec/3600
      logdata$readytime.ct <- as.POSIXct(logdata$Start.time)+(logdata$Total.time * 3600)
      logdata$starttime.ct <- as.POSIXct(logdata$Start.time)
      logdata$starttime <- strptime(logdata$starttime.ct,format="%Y-%m-%d")
      logdata$End.time <- as.POSIXct(logdata$Start.time)+(logdata$Total.time * 3600)
      logdata <- subset(logdata, as.character(starttime,format="%Y-%m-%d") == as.character(RepDate.1(),format="%Y-%m-%d") | (strptime(End.time,format="%Y-%m-%d") == as.character(RepDate.1(),format="%Y-%m-%d")))
      Utilization <- (sum(logdata$Total.time))/60
      Utilization <- paste(round(Utilization*100,digits=1),"%",sep="")
      output<-0
      #ymax.r = logdata$SqFt.hr/300
      ymax.r = 0
      logdata$jobname <- logdata$File.name
    }  
    p<-ggplot(logdata, aes(xmin = starttime.ct, xmax = readytime.ct, ymin = 0, ymax = 1-ymax.r, fill = factor(jobname))) + geom_rect(alpha = .9) +
      labs(title=paste(typeInput.1(),RepDate.1(), Utilization, output,sep=" "),x="Time of day",y="Run Time") + theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), legend.title = element_text(size=10),legend.title=element_blank()) + guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=5)) +
      scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%M", tz="US/Central"),breaks = date_breaks("1 hour"),expand=c(0,0)) +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = as.POSIXct(c(RepDate.1()+86400,RepDate.1()),format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", tz="US/Central")) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0,1)) 
    print(p)
    file<-ggsave("myplot.pdf",device = "pdf",plot = p,width=16, height=10,paper="special")
  })

  output$downloadplot <- downloadHandler(

    filename="myplot.pdf",  # desired file name on client 
    content=function(con) {
      file.copy("myplot.pdf", con)
    }
  )
  outputOptions(output, "downloadplot", suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Which part of your sidebar is supposed to be dynamic?  If you want to change the radio buttons, check `?updateRadioButtons`.

Comment: The values of the radial buttons and later for reading the correct csv logs files are pulled from a file called machines.csv. That is read into a data frame. The values for the radial buttons in the side bar are from that same csv file as t(Machine[1]). I want that csv file that is read to not just be hard coded like it is now but rather the filename derived from the tab name that is selected.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
Here, I hardcoded `choice_set` variable, but I suppose you can define it using external data file.

Keys.

- Keep your data in `reactiveValues`, so it can be referred to from server operations.
- Use `observeEvent(input$tabset, ...)` to trigger server operation only when the tabset value has been changed.
- Use `updateRadioButtons` to change the properties of the input components.

`R`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(radioButtons("radio", "radio", c("A", "B"))),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabset",
                  tabPanel("alphabet", value = "alpha"),
                  tabPanel("number", value = "number"))
)))


server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  RV <- reactiveValues(
    choise_set = list(
      alpha = c("A", "B"),
      number = c("1", "2", "3")
    )
  )

  observeEvent(input$tabset, {
    updateRadioButtons(session, "radio",
                       choices = RV$choise_set[[input$tabset]])
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: hat seems to get half way there. Do you know how I can make my plot render in the main panel no matter what tab I have selected?

Comment: For that, you will have to write separate `renderPlot` functions for each plot output in each tab.  If you have a lot of tabs, there are several ways for you to loop it.  This link may be helpful for looping (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624461/r-shiny-iterate-over-shinyui-output-elements).